# Lock should not be complete lock sometimes

Tags: feature-request, locked-questions

[image]

A question can be locked because of "high amount of off-topic comments". But it is preventing it from being voted on or edited, it prevents adding new answers to this question. I think that comments lock should only lock comments.

---

[image]

A question, locked because of "collaborative effort" should act like closing the question, only prevent adding new answers (voting and editing the question should be allowed).

---

[image]
Actulally, completely locked can be only a question with historical significance, or because of content dispute .

Comment: Yep, I need to start a bounty on [Make locking posts more granular](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124749/make-locking-posts-more-granular).